# Configuration Error

Tags: asp.net, html, config

I'm trying to load my webpage, `index.html`, and it is coming up on the browser with the following message.

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

```
Line 24:             during development.
Line 25:         -->
Line 26:        <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider"  enabled="true">
Line 27:            <providers>
Line 28:                <clear/>
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? Its say the problem is in a file called... web.config on Line: 26

Comment: please format your question properly in order to let us understand it better

Comment: I assume you're using ASP.Net?

Answer (score 1):

> Convert your virtual directory as Application in IIS.
>   Steps to do so:

```
- Click on Start
 - Open inetmgr
 - Right click on virtual directory and click on convert to
   application.
```